# How to run python script in a django class-based view?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

My Django app `models.py` has the following class:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

I am using class-based views so my `views.py` file has the following class:

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['name']
```

The HTTP form works perfectly and creates a new element in the database, but I need to call a function from an external python file upon the creation of a new instance of the class `Project`, the code I'm trying to run is:

```
import script
script.foo(self.object.name)
```

I'm trying to run the function `foo` inside the class `ProjectCreate` but I'm clueless, I tried using `get` and `dispatch` methods but it didn't work, I have read the documentation of [CreateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview) but I couldn't find my answer.

Should I use function-based views? or is there a solution for class-based views?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do this inside the model save method, rather than in the view, so it will be called whenever a new instance is created:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            script.foo(self)
        return super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you're sure you only want to do it from that one view, then you could override the view's `form_valid` method instead:

```
class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(ProjectCreate, self).form_valid(form)
        script.foo(self.object)
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your function only inside the view class you can simply override a `form_valid` method:

```
class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        result = super().form_valid(form)
        script.foo(self.object.name)
        return result
```

If you want to run the function after an every instance creation you can use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/) or override [model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save).

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. but overriding the `save()` function in the model class seems like a better solution.
Thank you again.